# Settings API - changing add_settings_field() output?

Tags: options, settings-api

I'm using [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) and wondering if there's any way of editing default output of [add_settings_field()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_field) function?

```
add_settings_field('the_field', 'bar', 'foo', 'page', 'section');      

function foo() {
    echo 'foo';
}
```

Outputs:

```
<table class="form-table">
  <tr valign="top">
    <th scope="row">bar</th>
    <td>foo</td>
    </tr>
```

How to get rid of these table tags and replace them with something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at `do_settings_fields()` (line 1125, `/wp-admin/includes/template.php`), you can see that the table information is hardcoded into the the settings API. If you wish to not use the table, you will need to develop your own settings functions.

Comment: Indeed. Using `do_settings_fields()` is basically using the API to determine the output markup. Doing so has its advantages (UI consistency, forward-compatibility), but if you *must* output custom markup, then you'll have to omit the `do_settings_fields()` call, and add your own, custom markup.

Comment: Thanks! :) I knew about template.php, but was hoping it's still changeable. This whole Settings API looks amazing at first but after some digging it's not so easy to customize and use at all :) And all the tutorials make me just more confused :)

Comment: As an author of one such tutorial, I'd love to know where you find it confusing, so that I can improve it. The intent is to *eliminate* confusion, rather than to create more. :)

Comment: It's really solid for just extending the core capabilities and core feel of wordpress.

Comment: @Chip Bennett, well, your tutorial is one of the greatest if not the greatest one out there, but... I'm a beginner when it comes to WordPress Settings and it's just in fact too complex (& I'm too stupid). It's confusing even more because it's on 10 pages, and I'm visual... :) I'd love to see your tutorial about Settings but 10 times shorter, just one register setting, a few sections a few fields and universal textarea/checkbox/input functions :) In fact I'm still not sure if it's possible to create a few basic input functions and just pass arguments to them using add_settings_field($args)? :)

Comment: @Wordpressor thanks for that feedback. I have been planning an updated version for some time now, and such feedback is invaluable.

Comment: @Chip Bennett, to be honest English is not my native language and all these really-too-long function names including "Varietals" and "oenology" are a bit confusig too (especially within code tags having horizontal scrolls so you can't actually see the whole code). Anyways I'll try to read your tutorial over and over again and I hope I'll get the results that I want without another StackExchange questions. Good luck and can't wait for the updated version! :)

Comment: @Wordpressor There is version of the tutorial in [one page](http://www.chipbennett.net/2011/02/17/incorporating-the-settings-api-in-wordpress-themes/?all=1).

Answer (score 0):

My custom function for this:

```
/**
 * Prints out one specified field from settings section.
 *
 * Based on:
 * @see do_settings_sections
 * 
 * @global array $wp_settings_sections  Storage array of all settings sections added to admin pages
 * @global array $wp_settings_fields    Storage array of settings fields and info about their pages/sections
 *
 * @param string $page                  The slug name of the page whose settings sections you want to output
 * @param string $field_id              Field ID for output
 */
public static function do_settings_section_field($page, $field_id) {
    global $wp_settings_sections, $wp_settings_fields;

    if ( ! isset( $wp_settings_sections[$page] ) )
        return;

    foreach ( (array) $wp_settings_sections[$page] as $section ) {

        if ( $section['callback'] )
            call_user_func( $section['callback'], $section );

        if ( ! isset( $wp_settings_fields[$page][$section['id']] ) )
            continue;

        foreach ( (array) $wp_settings_fields[$page][$section['id']] as $field ) {
            if ( $field['id'] !== $field_id )
                continue;

            call_user_func($field['callback'], $field['args']);
        }
    }
}
```

You can use this function instead of `do_settings_sections()`, with the same first arguments and field ID for render as second argument.